# Need to create a backup server to backup some windows files

Tags: server, windows, files, backup

I need to create a backup server to backup some windows files (.xls, .doc and etc...). It will be backup 10 windows pc (xp/7) every half hour. Those files will be on a few directories on those computer.

As we dont have much budget so I am thinking to use a desktop pc with ubuntu server installed on it to act for backup server.

I have some experience on setting up web server on ubuntu server but not too sure what spec I need to get for a backup server to handle this tasks.

I am thinking to use deltacopy for the windows pc and link to ubuntu server. But however, this process only can backup those saved files...

But what about those unsaved files? is there anyway for me to backup both saved and unsaved files? (files would be 100-200mb altogether.)

Backup the whole windows? but then this will be too big to backup as we wants to do backup every 30 minutes or 60 minutes.

any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! The only thing the server should provide in your scenario is *storage* as far as I can see. All other logic and subquestions you're asking for has either to do with hardware or the client software in Windows. I believe that makes this question mostly off-topic on this site. I would suggest to ask this on [Superuser.com](http://superuser.com) instead.

Comment: thanks for the reply, so is there have any way that I can achieve those tasks by ubuntu server instead of with those software?

Comment: Well, you *could* use a pull approach by setting up an Rsync or CIFS server on the Windows clients and have the Ubuntu server pull in the files to back up. However, currently your question is mostly Windows related. Without specifying a specific approach, I think this isn't really answerable here.

Answer (score 0):

Create a SAMBA server on the Ubuntu PC, then get some sort of software on the clients (Batch code, etc.) to send those directories that need to be backed up to your SAMBA server every half hour.